# jquery update price onclick radio or checkbox with condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: Check the Image]

I create a product form like this. When user select "product type" and "product size" then price will update. but after select size, if user change product type, price not update. I want also disable the size checkbox until user choose a product type.
Please have a look on my code on codepen.io or here.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/alshedupur/pen/YLOema

**HTML**

```
<div class="club_products row">

  <div class="club_product_image">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x350?text=PRODUCT" alt="coffee" class="club_product_wb"/>
  </div>

  <div class="club_product_form">
    <form action method="get">
    <div class="club_product_title">Select Product Type</div>

      <div class="pretty p-default p-round">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="wb" class="jm_product_type" />
        <div class="state p-success">
            <label>Whole Bean</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pretty p-default p-round">
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="rg" class="jm_product_type" />
        <div class="state p-success">
            <label>Roasted Grounded</label>
        </div>
      </div>

    <div class="club_product_title">Select Product Size</div>

      <div class="pretty p-icon p-smooth">
        <input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="4oz" class="update_price" />
        <div class="state p-success">
          <i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>
          <label>4 oz</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pretty p-icon p-smooth">
        <input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="8oz"  class="update_price" />
        <div class="state p-success">
          <i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>
          <label>8 oz</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pretty p-icon p-smooth">
        <input type="checkbox" name="size[]" value="16oz"  class="update_price" />
        <div class="state p-success">
          <i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>
          <label>16 oz</label>
        </div>
      </div>


    <div class="club_product_title">Select Subscription Length</div>   
      <div class="pretty p-default p-round">
        <input type="radio" name="length" value="30days" />
        <div class="state p-success">
            <label>30 Days</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pretty p-default p-round">
        <input type="radio" name="length" value="45days" />
        <div class="state p-success">
            <label>45 Days</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pretty p-default p-round">
        <input type="radio" name="length" value="60days" />
        <div class="state p-success">
            <label>60 Days</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="club_product_price">Price: $<span>0</span> USD</div>

      <input type="submit" name="join_our_club" value="Join Our Club" class="btn club_submit" />

    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('input[name=type]').on('click', function(){
    var type = $('input[name=type]:checked').val();

    if(type == 'wb'){
       $(document).on("change", ".update_price", function() {
          var sum = 0;
          $(".update_price:checked").each(function(){
            if($(this).val() == '4oz'){
              sum += 19.99;
            }
            if($(this).val() == '8oz'){
              sum += 35.99;
            }
            if($(this).val() == '16oz'){
              sum += 65.99;
            } 
          });
          $(".club_product_price span").text(sum.toFixed(2));
        });
    }
    if(type == 'rg'){
       $(document).on("change", ".update_price", function() {
          var sum = 0;
          $(".update_price:checked").each(function(){
            if($(this).val() == '4oz'){
              sum += 18.99;
            }
            if($(this).val() == '8oz'){
              sum += 36.99;
            }
            if($(this).val() == '16oz'){
              sum += 66.99;
            } 
          });
          $(".club_product_price span").text(sum.toFixed(2));
        });
    }

  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onChange function on checkboxes was registering inside the condition. So it was not triggering, rather registering on the current change of checkbox. And triggering for the last registered on change event.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('input[name=type],.update_price').on('click', function(){
    var type = $('input[name=type]:checked').val();

    if(type == 'wb'){
          var sum = 0;
          $(".update_price:checked").each(function(){
            if($(this).val() == '4oz'){
              sum += 19.99;
            }
            if($(this).val() == '8oz'){
              sum += 35.99;
            }
            if($(this).val() == '16oz'){
              sum += 65.99;
            } 
          });
          $(".club_product_price span").text(sum.toFixed(2));
    }
    if(type == 'rg'){
          var sum = 0;
          $(".update_price:checked").each(function(){
            if($(this).val() == '4oz'){
              sum += 18.99;
            }
            if($(this).val() == '8oz'){
              sum += 36.99;
            }
            if($(this).val() == '16oz'){
              sum += 66.99;
            } 
          });
          $(".club_product_price span").text(sum.toFixed(2));
    }

    });

    });
```

Comment: Awesome :) Thank you so much :)